# extjs4.1 How to add a specialkey event to a fields by mvc

Tags: extjs4.1

How to add a specialkey event to a numberfield by mvc.
Can anybody help me.
my from.panel textfield below

```
extend              : 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias               : 'widget.sv01i00900104',
    id                  : 'sv01i00900104',


{
            xtype             : 'numberfield',
            name              : 'rebatePercent',
            fieldLabel        : 'Percent:',
            flex              :  1,
            minValue          :  0,
            maxValue          :  100,
            mouseWheelEnabled :  false,
            hideTrigger       :  true,
            decimalPrecision  :  0,
            keyNavEnabled     :  false                                        
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I this it will help you

```
'sv01i00900104 numberfield[name = rebatePercent]' :{     
           specialkey: function (field, el) {
                if (el.getKey() == Ext.EventObject.ENTER){
                  console.log('hello world');
                }
              }
        }
```